# useEffect with document.addEvent-can't understand output

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am running the below code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = () => console.log(counter);
    //Do not do this
    document.body.addEventListener("click", listener);
    const cleanUp = () => console.log("cleaner");
    return cleanUp;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>+ Increment</button>
      <div>Count: {counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click on the button for the first time, I get the output in the console as:

```
cleaner 
0
1
```

After clicking the button first time  should cause a state change so the cleanup function returned  will be called and the event for document.body when counter was 0 should also be in the output but I don't understand why is there a 1 also in the output?

Edit:
If I use useEffect with counter as dependency and click on the button first time,I am still getting 1 in the output which shouldn't be possible if the useEffect is getting called after after the state update from counter 0 to counter 1.

Comment: You're adding an event listener on every render. In development mode with StrictMode, useEffects an be triggered multiple times (to catch this exact kind of thing). So you most likely have two listeners added by the time you click and therefore it increments and logs twice

Comment: you're using `useEffect()` without dependencies, the callback is executed every time _something_ changes (and that will cause to subscribe multiple times). Use `useEffect(() => { .... }, []);` if you want to execute that code only once. Moreover in the `cleanup` function you should unsubscribe from the event. If you're using `counter` in your callback then you should also include it as dependency (or your code will only capture the initial value)